# avconv timelapse error: no such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, libavcodec, unix, avconv

I'm trying to make a timelapse from a bunch of jpgs. They've been dumped in /home/sd/capture

The command I'm trying to use is:

```
avconv -r 30 -i /home/sd/capture/0%04d.jpeg output.mpeg
```

Is there something wrong with my syntax? Nothing I've tried has worked. All the files are renamed so that what I have works with what I've read Googling around.

Can any of you guys see what I've done wrong? Thanks in advance.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UIfl.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your files do not seems to have the suffix `.jpeg`. That might be a big no-no...

one way to do the renaming in bash is:

```
$ for i in ?????; do mv $i $i.jpeg; done
```